# Web RTC and open CV

Tags: opencv, web, video-streaming, webrtc

I need to build a web application which creates video call (point to point and conference call) via web RTC. While the video is being live streamed in real time, I've to create a queue of frames and feed it to an algorithm. I plan to use Open CV for this purpose. Is this approach fine or are there better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: your question is very high level, so it is hard to answer it. I am sure there are ways to combine opencv with webrtc in the same product, but the answer is really in the details. I'd say start with a reduced proof of concept and once you hit an implementation issue post your code here so people can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

opencv can't stream out anything on its own.

you'll probably have to dive into ffmpeg / gstreamer for this.

Comment: Open CV not for streaming, but to generate frames from the video stream for analysis.